# OpenRefine gives "Cannot create PyString with non-byte value" error

Tags: java, openrefine

When I try to run the openrefine.exe I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PyString with non-byte value error. I set JAVA_HOME path to my jdk folder and set the path of the java.exe file. And also installed Apache Maven and set its path too. I don't know why OpenRefine is not opening. And here is the full error:

```
Caused by:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.<init>(PythonInterpreter.java:99)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.<init>(PythonInterpreter.java:93)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.<init>(PythonInterpreter.java:70)
    at com.google.refine.jython.JythonEvaluable.<clinit>(JythonEvaluable.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:206)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:211)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:73)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__C__openrefine_3_5_2_webapp_extensions_jython_module_MOD_INF_controller_js_6._c_init_1(file:/C:/openrefine-3.5.2/webapp/extensions/jython/module/MOD-INF/controller.js:46)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__C__openrefine_3_5_2_webapp_extensions_jython_module_MOD_INF_controller_js_6.call(file:/C:/openrefine-3.5.2/webapp/extensions/jython/module/MOD-INF/controller.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:380)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3868)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.file__C__openrefine_3_5_2_webapp_extensions_jython_module_MOD_INF_controller_js_6.call(file:/C:/openrefine-3.5.2/webapp/extensions/jython/module/MOD-INF/controller.js)
    at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.ButterflyModuleImpl.scriptInit(ButterflyModuleImpl.java:636)
    at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.ButterflyModuleImpl.init(ButterflyModuleImpl.java:94)
    at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.initializeModule(Butterfly.java:476)
    at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.configure(Butterfly.java:451)
    at edu.mit.simile.butterfly.Butterfly.init(Butterfly.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$WrapperServlet.init(ServletHolder.java:1281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare(ServletHolder.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at com.google.refine.ValidateHostHandler.handle(ValidateHostHandler.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PyString with non-byte value
    at org.python.core.PyString.<init>(PyString.java:57)
    at org.python.core.PyString.<init>(PyString.java:70)
    at org.python.core.PyString.<init>(PyString.java:74)
    at org.python.core.Py.newString(Py.java:643)
    at org.python.core.PyJavaType.init(PyJavaType.java:543)
    at org.python.core.PyType$Registry.createType(PyType.java:477)
    at org.python.core.PyType$Registry.addFromClass(PyType.java:426)
    at org.python.core.PyType$Registry.resolveType(PyType.java:352)
    at org.python.core.PyType$Registry$1.computeValue(PyType.java:208)
    at org.python.core.PyType$Registry$1.computeValue(PyType.java:202)
    at java.lang.ClassValue.getFromHashMap(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassValue.getFromBackup(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassValue.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.PyType.fromClass(PyType.java:2137)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.<init>(PyObject.java:85)
    at org.python.core.PySingleton.<init>(PySingleton.java:9)
    at org.python.core.PyNotImplemented.<init>(PyNotImplemented.java:10)
    at org.python.core.Py.<clinit>(Py.java:66)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: What operating system is this on? If Windows, a path to java.exe shouldn't be necessary if you set JAVA_HOME. See also [the tech reference](https://docs.openrefine.org/technical-reference/build-test-run#set-up-jdk)

Comment: I'm using Windows10. I looked at the link and followed instructions but it is still the same

Comment: Please add some more information. Which versions of everything are you using, why are you using a development setup with Maven and a JDK, rather than a JRE without Maven? Also, have you seen [this](https://github.com/jython/jython/issues/20#issue-665668392), does that look similar to what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Is your JAVA_HOME is really well set?
Here's mine:

```
C:\Dev\OpenRefine>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-11.0.14.1_1

C:\Dev\OpenRefine>dir "%JAVA_HOME%"
 Le volume dans le lecteur C n’a pas de nom.
 Le numéro de série du volume est C071-7FF4

 Répertoire de C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-11.0.14.1_1

2022-02-09  21:00    <DIR>          .
2022-02-09  21:00    <DIR>          ..
2022-02-09  21:46    <DIR>          bin
2022-02-09  21:00    <DIR>          conf
2022-02-09  21:00    <DIR>          demo
2022-02-09  21:00    <DIR>          include
2022-02-09  21:00    <DIR>          jmods
2022-02-09  21:00    <DIR>          legal
2022-02-09  21:00    <DIR>          lib
2022-02-09  21:00             1 232 release
               1 fichier(s)            1 232 octets
               9 Rép(s)  75 901 587 456 octets libres

C:\Dev\OpenRefine>
```

You got to see the bin folder that contain `java.exe`.

Regards,
Antoine